# Multiple rows to single row multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is what my data looks like:

```
## ID ## ## Phase ## ## Phase Datet ## ## Phase Temp ## ## TempRecorded ##
23300200    Induction   2016-10-07        30               2016-10-07
23300200    Maintenance 2016-10-07        35               2016-10-07
23300200    Rewarming   2016-10-07        35.5             2016-10-07
```

I want to have it look like this:

```
## ID ## ## Induction Phase ## ## Induction Phase Datet ## ## Induction Phase Temp ## ## Induction TempRecorded ## ## ID ## ## Maintenance Phase ## ## Maintenance Phase Datet ## ## Maintenance Phase Temp ## ## Maintenance TempRecorded ##
23300200    Induction                    2016-10-07                   30                     2016-10-07                          Maintenance                2016-10-07                  35                              2016-10-07
```

Comment: check [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Good luck with that. SO contributors are not a code writing service. Show effort. Provide code that you have tried. List errors you encountered, or hire someone to write this for you.

Comment: As a starter pointer you will need to pivot on each of the Phase values. As you then have multiple values per phase and want them separately, you might want to consider how you can expand the Pivot further to include multiple column values.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague provided me with a solution

```
SELECT I.*, M.*,R.*
FROM
(select * from #PhaseTemp where ValueText = 'Induction') I
LEFT JOIN (select * from #PhaseTemp where ValueText = 'Maintenance') M ON M.ClientGUID = I.ClientGUID
LEFT JOIN (select * from #PhaseTemp where ValueText = 'Rewarming') R ON R.CLIENTGUID = I.CLIENTGUID
```